# Why is a hash literal called a hash literal in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

This is probably something you learn in programming 101.

*Disclaimer: I have no formal programming training. I am self-taught.*

For me, literal hash is like what [this](http://codelikethis.com/lessons/ruby_basics/hashes) website suggests: a third editable hash called "corned beef hash".

[image]

In Ruby, you have two data types:

- hash
- hash literals

Why is one called a literal? Is it because you literally type out the associative array? The website above claims it is because the definition is inline. If so, why is the hash not also called literal when you can type it out like this:

```
states = Hash.new

states["CA"] = "California"
states["MA"] = "Massachusetts"
states["NY"] = "New York"

states["MA"].reverse #=> "sttesuhcassaM"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The data type is just one: `Hash`. `Hash` is a class. You can instantiate objects and use them

```
h = Hash.new
h.store("CA", "California")
h["MA"] = "Massachusetts"
```

A literal is just a shortcut which let you create objects of that class without explicitly use that class.

```
h = { "CA" => "California", "MA" => "Massachusetts" }
```

Same for `Array`s

```
a = Array.new
a.push(1)
a << 2
```

Or, with `array` literal

```
a = [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 5):

Your confusion stems from this misconception:

> In Ruby, you have two data types:
>
> - hash
> - hash literals

Firstly, there are many more data structures in the Ruby core.

But secondly, there is no such thing as "literal hash". Hash literals refer to syntax sugar for defining hashes in place, aka literally.

```
# This is a hash literal
x = {foo: 42, bar: :baz}

# This is not a hash literal
x = Hash.new
x[:foo] = 42
x[:bar] = :baz
```

They are completely identical. The only difference is one is more convenient, while the other is more dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

A literal is a fixed value.

It cannot be edited, unless you assign it to a variable and then modify that (although then of course you are not actually modifying the literal).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(computer_programming)

So you can assign a literal to a variable, compare a variable to a literal, compare two literals, but you cannot in general modify a literal directly.

Edit: Note that cases where a literal is modified turn out to be creating a new object, unlike the same operation performed on a variable.

```
2.2.5 :001 > "foo".upcase!
 => "FOO" 
2.2.5 :002 > "foo".object_id
 => 2204993280 
2.2.5 :003 > "foo".upcase!.object_id
 => 2204964760 
2.2.5 :004 > x = "foo"
 => "foo" 
2.2.5 :005 > x.object_id
 => 2204927520 
2.2.5 :006 > x.upcase!.object_id
 => 2204927520 
2.2.5 :007 >
```

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot be edited / modified"?. `"foo"` is a string literal and `"foo".upcase!` will modify it.

Comment: @stefan No, it looks like it does, but it creates a new object. See demo.

Comment: That's because the literal `"foo"` creates a new object every time, but `upcase!` does modify the receiver: `"foo".tap { |s| p s.object_id }.upcase!.tap { |s| p s.object_id }`

Comment: `"foo".tap { |s| p s.object_id }.upcase!.tap { |s| p s.object_id }
47400638281080
47400638281080`